# The meaning of objects in Django

Tags: python, django, dictionary

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
                return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'error':'Username has already been taken'})

            except User.DoesNotExist:
                user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
                login(request, user)
                return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'error':'Passwords didn\'t match'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html')
```

In the following program, the line

`user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])`

is confusing me in some point. I know that if I have the dictionary `d = {word1 : definition1, word2 : definition2}`, then `d.get[word1]` will output `definition1` (the `id` of `word1`). So `User.objects` is a dictionary, because of the structure `dict.get()`. I have a little problem with this part of the line.

Could anyone be able to explain to me what is the meaning of `objects`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objects` is a reference to the model's [Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/), whos sole purpose is to handle the database queries to retrieve the required data from a database.

Although it has a method `get` that shares the same name as the `get` method of a dictionary, they do not do the same thing internally in respect to where the data is retrieved from.